# I am trying to load a RecyclerView from clicking a button in my current RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

What I want to do is click a button in my current RecyclerView that will display the corresponding RecyclerView with the data I am looking for. Is it possible to do this? I want each button on each item to display different data held in recyclerView

Comment: do you mean each item in your recyclerview is expandable?

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: what I mean is I have multiple RecyclerViews set up each for a different attendance sheet for specific modules. I want to click  a button on a card  in my recyclerview that will display the recyclerview holding the data for the correct module.

Comment: If the data in those modules is just text, and the list is small (maybe less than 20 items), I would just use a ListView for them. Keep the main outer RecyclerView but use ListViews instead of nesting more RecyclerViews

Comment: can you share code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Just have a click on a recyclerview item launch a fragment that displays the second recyclerview.  Nesting recyclerviews causes performance issues and is not good practice.

Comment: I need the item being clicked to correspond to the correct recyclerview. So the id of the item being clicked needs to open the the recyclerView with the matchind ID. Can this be done?

Comment: Sure. In the onClick method for the item, launch a new fragment or activity and pass the Id through in the bundle. Then in that new activity or fragment, load the data that corresponds with your ID into a recyclerview. If you post code, it would help.